# MalformedByteSequenceException exception when try to parse with DOM

Tags: java, domparser

I have this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    Document document = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Chaplin");

        //Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8");
        document = builder.parse(url.openStream());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

On the page I tried to process, I got the following exception:

> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

How can I change the page to UTF-8? Alternatively, what other way(s) could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read HTML with an XML parser. Your character set is only the start of your problems.

You will need a proper parser for HTML. If you want a DOM-like structure, I recommend http://jsoup.org/. If you just want the text, you can use Apache Tika.

If you insist on feeding it to an XML parser, you can read the bytes into a buffer, and then use the character encoding detector from Tika to discover the encoding and then convert to a String, and feed the String to the DOM parser.